# What are the parameters pass onto fn in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

Here is the definition of prompt in ExtJS:
Ext.window.MessageBox.prompt( title, msg, [fn], [scope], [multiline], [value] ).

It is clear that fn is a function. But I'm always confused what parameters will be passed onto the fn. How can I find it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the docs, scroll down to the fn parameter: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox-method-show

```
Parameters
buttonId : String
The ID of the button pressed, one of:

ok
yes
no
cancel
text : String
Value of the input field if either prompt or multiline is true
opt : Object
The config object passed to show.
```